# Inconsistent error message DOM betweeen jQuery validation and Postback

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My error message html structure from jQuery validation and from postbacks are different causing my validation errors to display differently. I need the nested span tag within the span.field-validation-error because I use CSS to add the (x) icon before the message like the one you see on the Description error message.

This is the error message from jQuery validation.

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Code" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span id="Code-error" class="">The Description field is required.</span>
</span>
```

notice that on the banner url validation message, there's no span tag within the span.field-validation-error.

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="BannerUrl" data-valmsg-replace="true">
   The Banner Image field is required.
</span>
```

This is the view cshtml file markup I have.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description):
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { rows = 5, cols = 5, @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter your team description" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Description)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BannerUrl):
    <input id="BannerUrl" name="BannerUrl" type="file" class="file-styled">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BannerUrl)
</div>
```

Why does the error message html from jquery validation different from the error message html that's generated after postback?

[image]

EDIT:

Below is the CSS that adds the (X) icon before the error message. What I really want it to do is for the icon to show up in front of the error message that comes from a postback (no nested span) and also the error message from jquery validation (nested span).

```
.field-validation-error > span:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    content: "\ed63";
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `jquery.validate` is written by completely separate developers that the MVC framework, and `jquery.validate` requires the definition of an `errorElement` as a container for the message (by default its a `<label>` but `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` overrides that to use a `<span>`

Comment: Is there a way to override the error message HTML that comes back from a postback?

Comment: When returning a view with `ModelState` errors, the `ValidationMessageFor()` just renders the message text inside the `<span>` element. Unless you were to write your own extension method, then no. But why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe if I override it to add that extra span tag within the span.field-validation-error then I could get the same effect the Description javascript error.

Comment: You mean you want the 'icon' shown in the first image? It would be far easier to just include script to add the `<span>` (using `.wrapInner()`). But you must have some css or javascript/plugin that is adding that icon anyway - what is it?

Comment: I am using the ":before" and "content" property in CSS to add the icon into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134933/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-platypus-maximus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jquery.validate.js` plugin and the MVC framework are developed by separate teams (jquery.validate is not associated with Microsoft). The MVC framework just uses `jquery.validate.js` for client side validation (and use `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to add the rules to `jquery.validate.js`).

You could create you own `HtmlHelper` extension to generate the inner `<span>` element server side. For example, copy the [ValidationExtensions.cs source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs) and modify the `private static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageHelper(...)` method so that instead of `builder.SetInnerText(validationMessage);` you use `builder.InnerHtml = xx;` where `xx` is a `TagBuilder` that builds a `<span>` containing the error message.

However, it would be easier to just use some javascript to wrap the inner text inside a `<span>` element when the page is first loaded

```
// Get all the elements generated by ValidationMessageFor() that have an error
var errors = $('.field-validation-error');
$.each(errors, function (index, item) {
    // Wrap the text in a span element
    $(this).wrapInner('<span></span>');
})
```

Note that the `jquery.validate` plugin also adds an `id` attribute to the span based on the property name. It does not appear that you need that based on your css, however, if you do want to include that, then you can use

```
$.each(errors, function (index, item) {
    var id = $(this).data('valmsg-for').replace(/[\.\[\]]/g, "_") + '-error';
    var span = $('<span></span>').attr('id', id);
    $(this).wrapInner(span);
})
```

Another option would be to wrap each `ValidationMessageFor()` inside an element, for example

```
<span class="error">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)
</span>
```

and modify the css selector

```
.error > .field-validation-error:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    ....
}
```